# Java Regex to parse Forex pair from file name

Tags: java, regex

I'm having trouble getting a Java regex to parse something from a file name. I'm presented with a GUI interface to enter a Pattern and Replacement, for each file name similarly named as "level1EUR__USD@TRUEFX_2009_05_01_2016_12_30.txt"

Here's the screenshot of the GUI:
[image]

I know it's a Java Regex but I cant seem to get it right.

What is a regex to replace **"EUR__USD"** to **"EUR/USD"**

**Input:**

**"level1EUR__USD@TRUEFX_2009_05_01_2016_12_30"**?

**Output:**

**level1EUR/USD@TRUEFX_2009_05_01_2016_12_30**

Comment: is the pattern always the same?

Comment: What should be the result?

Comment: yes, the pattern is the same for all files and the file names are in the same format

Comment: Try `^\w*?([A-Z]{3})_+([A-Z]{3}).*` to replace with `$1/$2`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew tyvm that works. Post as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
^\w*?([A-Z]{3})_+([A-Z]{3}).*
```

and replace with `$1/$2`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a69FNX/1).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `\w*?` - 0+ word chars, as few as possible
- `([A-Z]{3})` -  Group 1 (referred to with `$1` in the replacement pattern): 3 uppercase ASCII letters
- `_+` - 1 or more `_` chars
- `([A-Z]{3})` - Group 2 (referred to with `$2` in the replacement pattern): 3 uppercase ASCII letters
- `.*` - the rest of the line

Comment: short regex "([A-Z]{3})_+([A-Z]{3})", then replace with "$1/$2"

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. Will mark in 4min